# ansible AnsibleUndefinedVariable error while storing logs in a file

Tags: ansible

I am using a playbook to un-install a software program and the playbook works.
This playbook first comfirms the binary path of the software using the `stat` module and the uses the `when` condition to check if it exists and based on that it performs the actions..

I'm also using the `shell` module to run the un-installation. Below one is my playbook

```
---
- name: Un-Install altris
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  strategy: free
  serial: 100
  tasks:
  - name: Check if altris stop/start path exists
    stat: path=/opt/altiris/notification/nsagent/bin/rcscript
    register: altris_status

  - name: stop the altris if path exits
    shell: |
      echo `hostname`
      echo "-------------------------------"
      /opt/altiris/notification/nsagent/bin/rcscript stop
    when: altris_status.stat.exists == True
    register: altris_stop

  - name: Check if uninstall binary ptah exists
    stat: path=/opt/altiris/notification/nsagent/bin/aex-uninstall
    register: altris_uninstall

  - name: un-installing altris
    shell: |
      echo `hostname`
      echo "-------------------------------"
      yes | /opt/altiris/notification/nsagent/bin/aex-uninstall
    when: altris_uninstall.stat.exists == True
    register: altris_trim

#############  Storing the logs locally for the STDOUT ############
  - name: Storing the remote Hosts Output locally for altris
    #lineinfile: create=yes dest=/Karn/altris_uninstall.logs  line="{{ altris_trim.stdout }}"
    lineinfile: create=yes dest=/Karn/test_uninstall.logs  line="{{ altris_trim.stdout }}"
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

  - name: Storing the remote Hosts Output locally for altris
    #lineinfile: create=yes dest=/Karn/altris1_stop.logs  line="{{ altris_stop.stdout }}"
    lineinfile: create=yes dest=/Karn/test_stop.logs  line="{{ altris_stop.stdout }}"
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

> Note: when i run the playbook its works fine, but the error only appears where it
>   dont find the binary path for un-installation and throws the below
>   mesg errror:

```
[root@dev-ops Karn]# ansible-playbook altris_unistall2.yml

PLAY [Un-Install altris] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
Friday 15 December 2017  10:35:50 +0530 (0:00:00.112)       0:00:00.112 *******

TASK [Check if altris stop/start path exists] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [dev-oracle]
Friday 15 December 2017  10:36:01 +0530 (0:00:10.179)       0:00:10.292 *******

TASK [stop the altris if path exits] ********************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [dev-oracle]
Friday 15 December 2017  10:36:01 +0530 (0:00:00.019)       0:00:10.311 *******

TASK [Check if uninstall binary ptah exists] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [dev-oracle]
Friday 15 December 2017  10:36:11 +0530 (0:00:10.483)       0:00:20.795 *******

TASK [un-installing altris] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [dev-oracle]
Friday 15 December 2017  10:36:11 +0530 (0:00:00.022)       0:00:20.817 *******

TASK [Storing the remote Hosts Output locally for altris] ***********************************************************************************************************
fatal: [dev-oracle]: FAILED! => {
    "failed": true
}

MSG:

The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'

The error appears to have been in '/Karn/altris_unistall2.yml': line 33, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

#############  Storing the logs locally for the STDOUT ############
  - name: Storing the remote Hosts Output locally for altris
    ^ here

exception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>
exception: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'

        to retry, use: --limit @/Karn/altris_unistall2.retry

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
dev-oracle                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Friday 15 December 2017  10:36:11 +0530 (0:00:00.037)       0:00:20.854 *******
===============================================================================
Check if uninstall binary ptah exists ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 10.48s
Check if altris stop/start path exists ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 10.18s
Storing the remote Hosts Output locally for altris ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.04s
un-installing altris ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.02s
stop the altris if path exits -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.02s
```

Please susggest if any chnage i need to have in my playbook..
something like ingore_error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`un-installing altris` task gets skipped, so `altris_trim` does not contain `stdout` key.

You either need to add `when: stdout in altris_trim` to the `Storing the remote Hosts Output locally for altris` or use the same condition as for `un-installing altris`.

The same applies to the next task and `altris_stop.stdout`.